# How to create a node js API for which users can subscribe to listen to events?

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to create and node.js api to which users can subscribe to get event notifications?

I created the below API and was able to call the API using python ,however its not clear to me how can folks subscribe to it?

How can folks subscribe to this API to get notification of New root build released?what do I need to change?

**node.js API**

```
app.get("/api/root_event_notification", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.params)
  var events = require('events');
  var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

  //Create an event handler:
  var myEventHandler = function () {
    console.log('new_root_announced!');
    res.status(200).json({
          message: "New root build released!",
          posts: req.query.params
        });
  }


import requests
```

python call

```
input_json = {'BATS':'678910','root_version':'12A12'}
url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/root_event_notification?params=%s'%input_json
response = requests.get(url)
print response.text
```

OUTPUT:-

```
{"message":"New root build released!","posts":"{'root_version': '12A12', 'BATS': '678910'}"}
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to have a remote computer subscribe to some sort of notifications from your server?  Or a local API that other code within your server code subscribes to notifications?  These are two completely different things.  For your existing implementation, you can't just postpone sending an http response for an arbitrary amount of time.  Both client and server (and sometimes the hosting provider's infrastructure) will timeout the http request after some number of minutes.

Comment: @jfriend00 - its the former, have a remote computer subscribe to notification from server

Comment: The easiest approach would be to poll the server for updates alternativly you could look into using a webhook of sorts.

Comment: @MadisonCourto - while polling for updates,how would the client differentiate between newer update and older updates ,there could be bunch of updates and the client would want to know only when .a new update has been added?

Comment: A time stamp or unique id?

Comment: I want to set up a event notification system,I am looking for ideas on this line

Answer (score 2):

You can't just postpone sending an http response for an arbitrary amount of time. Both client and server (and sometimes the hosting provider's infrastructure) will timeout the http request after some number of minutes.  There are various tricks to try to keep the http connection alive, but all have limitations.

Using web technologies, the usual options for get clients getting updated server data:

1. **http polling** (client regularly polls the server).  There's also a long polling adaptation version of this that attempts to improve efficiency a bit.
2. **Websocket.**  Clients makes a websocket connection to the server which is a lasting, persistent connection.  Then either client or server can send data/events of this connection at any time, allowing the server to efficiently send notifications to the client at any time.
3. **Server Sent Events (SSE).**  This is a newer http technology that allows one-way notification from server to client using some modified http technology.

Since a server cannot typically connect directly to a client due to firewall and public IP address issues, the usual mechanism for a server to notify a client is to use either a persistent webSocket connection from client to server over which either side can then send webSocket packets or use the newer SSE (server sent events) which allows some server events to be sent to a client over a long lasting connection.

The client can also "poll" the server repeatedly, but this is not really an event notification system (and not particularly efficient or timely) as much as it is some state that the client can check.

Comment: but sounds like 'polling' is a  bad idea compared to event notification system, why unncessarily 'poll' and waste resources when an event can  trigger the necessary job right away?what do you think?

Comment: @user2125827 - Yes, polling is inefficient and, as I said, not really an event notification system.  Whether it's appropriate or not depends entirely upon the situation.

Comment: ya,thats why I want to set up a event notification system,I am looking for ideas on this line

Comment: @user2125827 - Did you read my answer?  I offered you two technologies that allow for real notification (webSocket and SSE).

Comment: @may be my request is not as complex as you are thinking?all I need is to send an event (in JSON format) to users who subscribe to the node.js API

Comment: can you please provide a specific example using SSE or webSocket on how this can be done?

Comment: @user2125827 - There are hundreds of relevant tutorials on the web.  I'm not going to write a complete tutorial on both client and server sides here in this answer.  Please do some research yourself, study, try and then write a new question if you get stuck and have a specific problem implementing one of them.

Comment: @user2125827 SSE is what you're looking for:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events

Comment: I want to be able to use SSE in which clients are NOT browsers,all the examples I see are where the clients are browsers, is there an example to use SSE where the API is in node.js and the client is a python script?

Comment: @user2125827 - [SSE clients from python](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+sse+with+python+client).  [SSE server-side from node.js](https://medium.com/@moinism/using-nodejs-for-uni-directional-event-streaming-sse-c80538e6e82e).  Google is your friend here as that's all I did.