# Is there a way I can host and stream data to a website from nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to take data from a chat, like one similar to discord.js and host a website and stream data to it in real time without a refresh of the site

I've tried using res.write with http but that only works once and it would require a restart,
also I know that I'm using express to start the website but I'm ok with using anything.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var shajs = require('sha.js')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  function coolfunc() {
    res.send(shajs('sha256').update('42').digest('hex'))
  }
  setInterval(coolfunc, 1000)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

no expectations but I just wanna know if it's possible and something that I could use to do it

Comment: Clients would want to make a webSocket or socket.io connection to your server and then the server can freely send the clients data whenever it wants.  Your client-side Javascript then receives that data and inserts it into the web page DOM.

Comment: See [How client can get server events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863883/how-to-create-a-node-js-api-for-which-users-can-subscribe-to-listen-to-events/57864062#57864062)